# Facebook AppRequest error on Android

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

This is with the Facebook SDK for Unity - forgot to mention that.

I have an app on Facebook Canvas that I've recently been working with an Android version of it. In my app, the player can request lives from friends, which uses the following code:

```
FB.AppRequest("Can you send me an extra life? I'm out!", //Message
    Facebook.OGActionType.AskFor,  //ActionID
    GameMgr.GetRequestObject("reqlife").ID, //ObjectID
    friendIDs, //to:
    "reqlife", //data:
    "I need a new life!", //title:
    appRequestCallback);
```

The object id of the OG life object I created is retrieved on the third line. On the fourth line, friendIDs is an array of Facebook friend IDs (which have the app installed) to send the request to, just as side notes.

With my Canvas App, this works perfectly fine. With my Android version of the same app, I get an error returned to the app immediately:

```
{"error":"{FacebookServiceException: httpResponseCode -1, facebookErrorCode: 100,
facebookErrorType: null, message: null}","to":[]}
```

I realize it's JSON, but was a simple read and faster to just type it in. I do have the Android platform added in my settings, and I do have the same OG approvals on the Android side as the Canvas app side from my best unserstanding.

I'm hoping somebody can point out what I've not done, or what direction I need to go in order for this to work on the Android platform of my app.

Answer (score 0):

After countless hours of trying different things, I finally re-created an instance of my object using the Object Browser tool, and voila everything now works on both platforms. Not sure if having created it before adding the Android platform created some sort of ordering issue, or what the reason was, but that fixed this issue for me.

Comment: @GastonClaret -> This is why links are unappreciated.

Comment: @Christian.tucker My bad, copied the link wrong...

http://www.bigfootgaming.net/blog/tutorials/facebook-open-graph-objects-in-unity3d/